# How best do I structure my mongodb database to store my Reactjs frontend values?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am building a web blog content management system and I am using the journey to learn Nodejs, Reactjs and Mongodb. What I want to do now is create a system whereby whoever that is an admin can create, edit and delete some frontend values such as website name, sub-name, header image. The person will also be able to do the same things on the sidebar which has the bio image and bio content. In order to do these things, I have to store these values somewhere and I am storing them inside my Mongodb database to my best of understanding.

So, I have created each of these values as a separate collection in my database. For instance, there is a collection called websitename, sitesubname, headerImage, sidebarImage, sidebarContent, headerColour, backgroundColour, textColour, etc.
Each of these collections have their own codes to create, edit, delete and fetch in my Nodejs. Is this the best way or is there a way to place them all in one collection in Mongodb?

Comment: Designing a database structure is called as Data Modeling - see the MongoDB [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/), for some ideas.

Comment: I know the basics...I am just asking if the way I structured this is best approach for what I want to do.